# Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor. Compilation error.The constructor is undefined

Tags: lombok

I'm trying to use Lombok in Eclipse STS following the examples in the book "Learn Microservices with Spring Boot" of Apress

When I wrote the class code for the Multiplication domain class I obtained an compile error: "The constructor Multiplication(int, int) is undefined".

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.domain;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

/**
 * This class represents a Multiplication (a * b).
 */
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public final class Multiplication {

    // Both factors
    private final int factorA;
    private final int factorB;

    // Empty constructor for JSON (de)serialization
    Multiplication() {
        this(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you install the lombok plugin to your Eclipse, as described [here](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)? Please check the "About Eclipse" dialog to verify that the plugin is installed correctly.

Comment: The Multiplication class compiles, there is sth wrong with your environment. Besides that, there is no a multiply function in the class ;)

Comment: You both are right. I omitted to stop STS/eclipse and start it again. So ashamed.

Comment: @GratinianoLozano Don't add "SOLVED" to the beginning of the post's title if you've gotten the answer. If you want to indicate that this question has an acceptable answer then [add the answer and mark it as Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac:

#### 1. Help -> Install New Software

[image]

#### 2. Work with: Lombok - https://projectlombok.org/p2

[image]

#### 3. Restart Spring Tool Suite, clean and rebuild the project.

[image]